# How to include JDBC driver with .war file

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, odbc, war

What do I need to do to include the JDBC-ODBC drivers in my web application? What library are these found in? Thanks.
Note: I need the MS Access jdbc driver only.

Comment: Or is this part of the bootstrap classes? I am asking this question because my application is not able to connect to the database when deployed as a .war, even though it can connect when I am running it through eclipse directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the JRE, no need to include it.

Comment: Do you have any idea why, then, my web app is not able to access the database when deployed as a war but it is when I run it through eclipse? Is my Tomcat server just screwed up somehow?

Comment: @joseph: The original question is already been answered. For new questions, press `Ask Question` button on right top.